# Floating point not working in shell

Tags: shell

I'm trying to write a program that can compute the average result given an integer N

```
 #!/bin/sh
    
    CTR=0
    sum=0
    read N
    
    while [ $CTR -ne $N ]; do
      read integer;
      sum=$(( $integer + $sum ))
      CTR=$(( $CTR + 1 ))
    done 
    
    printf '%.3f\n' "$(( $sum * 1/ $N ))"
```

This was my input when compiling :

```
2
5
6
```

**Expected output**
5.500

**Actual output**
5.000

Why is that ?

Comment: Yes, integer arithmetic only in bash or sh. With ksh you would say `float sum N`, then the rest of the script should work as written.

Comment: @Gaston there's no need to edit your question to include Answers; if your question is a duplicate, the Answers on that duplicate question are intended to answer this question as well.